# Creating plugin scanner with StructureMap

Tags: structuremap

I'm attempting to write a StructureMap plugin scanner for Payment Gateway implementations.  I have created an IPaymentGateway interface in an external library.  I have created several implementations of IPaymentGateway and put those .dlls in my C:\Extensions\ folder.

Here is my StructureMap configuration:

```
         ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Scan(scanner =>
            {
                scanner.AssembliesFromPath(@"C:\Extensions\");
            });
        });
```

Here is my calling code:

```
var list = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IPaymentGateway>().ToList();
list.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.FriendlyName));
```

I would expect that the list should contain each of my implementations of IPaymentGateway, but it doesn't contain anything.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the types using the scanner:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.Scan(scanner =>
    {
      scanner.AssembliesFromPath(@"C:\Extensions\");
      scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IPaymentGateway>();
    });
```

Comment: Weird, I swear I did that before and it didn't make a difference.  Now it works.  Must be those darn gremlins again.