# StructureMap Dynamically loading Plugin Dll's

Tags: c#, ioc-container, structuremap

Problem:
Loading Plugins into a console app(Windows Service Eventually) and running code in the plug in dll's

Research: 
StructureMap Docs(of course)
A few stackoverflow threads this one being the closest.
[Creating plugin scanner with StructureMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299510/creating-plugin-scanner-with-structuremap)

I have 3 projects:
Console App (Driver)
2 Class libraries

Console App

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(cfg => cfg.Scan(scanner =>
    {
        scanner.AssembliesFromPath(@"PATH TO PLUGIN DIR");
        scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IPlugable>();
    }));

    var list = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IPlugable>();

    foreach (var plug in list)
    {
        plug.Run();
    }
}

public interface IPlugable
{
    void Run();
}
```

Plugin_2

```
public interface IPlugable
{      
    void Run();
}

public class PlugIn2 : IPlugable
{    
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + "fired!");
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface IPlugable
{     
    void Run();
}

public class PlugIn1 : IPlugable
{          
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name + "fired!");
    }
}
```

The Output:

```
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IPlugable>();
```

returns no objects :(
Desired Output:
2 Object Instances of Plugin_1 & Plugin_2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the output of ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using 3 different interfaces. They are all called "IPlugable", but reside in different namespaces, hence they are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the answer I am going with..
Managed Extensibility Framework
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx

Got to love it when you find a new framework to find the exact solution to your problem.